# Not Adding Element to Dictionary - RPG Item System

Tags: python

I am implementing an inventory system into my RPG, I am trying to make it so that it gives me the item name, weight, the number of items, etc. I am having trouble with getting the number of items. So here is my code;

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, damage, armor, weight, value, itype, rarity):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.armor = armor
        self.weight = weight
        self.value = value
        self.itype = itype
        self.rarity = rarity


class Inventory():

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item):

        self.items[item.name] = item

    def print_items(self):
        print('\t'.join(['Name', 'Atk', 'Arm', 'Kg', 'Val', 'Type', 'Rarity']))

        for item in self.items.values():
            print('\t'.join([str(x) for x in [item.name, item.damage, item.armor, item.weight, item.value, item.itype, item.rarity]]))

Items = {
    'dragonbane': Item('Dragon bane', 60, 0, 5, 1000, 'Weapon', '.oOo. LEGENDARY .oOo.'), # Name, Damage, Armour, Weight, Type, Rarity
    'trainingsword': Item('Training Sword', 2, 0, 5, 10, 'Weapon', '[ Common ]')} 

inventory = Inventory()

inventory.add_item(Items['dragonbane']

inventory.print_items()
```

Output:

```
Name    Atk Arm Kg  Val Type    Rarity
Dragon bane 60  0   5   1000    Weapon  .oOo. LEGENDARY .oOo.
```

But if I were to add two Dragon Banes, it would only print Dragon Banes once. I simply cannot figure out how to add a system that counts how many of one item the player has.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You're using a `dict` whose keys are the item names.  That means you can have only one item per name.  If you want multiple items to have the same name, then either don't use a `dict` or else use a different key that *is* unique.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks! I have been trying to detect if the element was there, and then put the number in the dictionary. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use and UID ( Unique ID ) instead of the item name as Identifier for the Items.

also for example:

```
def get_uid():
    return random.randint(123456789,987654321)
#here you need to check also for already existing numbers - it's just an example

self.items[get_uid()] = item
```

Comment: Don't use this `get_uid` function.  It's completely unnecessary.  If you want a unique id, you can use `id(object)` which is a builtin function.  Or you can use the class instance itself as the `dict` key, i.e. `d[object] = object`. Or better yet, don't use a `dict` at all, use a `set`.

Comment: In fact, you may only need a `list` - it's not clear how the data is being accessed, but if you just need to be able to iterate over it, then a `list` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In Item construction, simply add:
self.uid= randint(1, 99999999)

*PS: Don't forget to import on top the random module (from random import randint).